# dynamically build up query - SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SkF6.png)

I am trying to build a dynamic query within SQL that adds the 'Statement' Column based of the 'Field Options' As shown in the table Image. (Please refer to table picture attached)

If 'Field Options' = A then Field Name = 'SINGLE PAY'. This should then Populate the 'Statement' column as 'SELECT SINGLE PAY FROM'...

**How can I use a cursor to iterate through each row of my table and build a third column for me called 'Statement'?**

```
enter codeDECLARE @field_option nvarchar(max) = 'B'
DECLARE @field_name nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @statement nvarchar(max)

IF @field_option = 'A'
BEGIN
    SET @field_name = 'Single Pay'
    SET @statement = 'SELECT '+ @field_name+'...'
    SELECT @field_option AS 'Field_Option', @field_name            AS 'Field_Name', @statement AS 'Statement'
    INTO new_table
    SELECT * FROM new_table;
END

ELSE IF @field_option = 'B'
BEGIN
    SET @field_name = 'Double Pay'
    SET @statement = 'SELECT '+ @field_name+'...'
    SELECT @field_option AS 'Field_Option', @field_name     AS 'Field_Name', @statement AS 'Statement'
    INTO new_table
    SELECT * FROM new_table;
END here
```

Problem I am facing is that when I try to execute the query second time for example with option 'B' I get error "There is already an object named 'new_table' in the database."

How do I add new row to my existing "new_table"? Can someone please Guide?

Comment: Using dynamic queries is very often the result of a bad table design or misusing SQL. What is it good for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
DECLARE @field_option nvarchar(max) = 'B'
DECLARE @field_name nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @statement nvarchar(max)

IF OBJECT_ID('new_table') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE new_table

IF @field_option = 'A'
BEGIN
    SET @field_name = 'Single Pay'
    SET @statement = 'SELECT '+ @field_name+'...'
    SELECT @field_option AS 'Field_Option', @field_name            AS 'Field_Name', @statement AS 'Statement'
    INTO new_table
    SELECT * FROM new_table;
END

ELSE IF @field_option = 'B'
BEGIN
    SET @field_name = 'Double Pay'
    SET @statement = 'SELECT '+ @field_name+'...'
    SELECT @field_option AS 'Field_Option', @field_name     AS 'Field_Name', @statement AS 'Statement'
    INTO new_table
    SELECT * FROM new_table;
END
```

After you ran the statement once (while testing I would guess) the table got made.  Now it's there and doesn't go away on it's own.  So throw an check to see if it exists at the top and drop it.  Alternatively you could look into using:

- #temp tables
- table variables

Comment: thanks for your suggestion: How can I use a cursor to iterate through each row of my table and build a third column for me called 'Statement'?

Comment: @Jazzy You should mark this answer correct and ask a new one.  You don't want to keep editing the same question, otherwise the questions and answers get all jumbled up, and we don't want that :)  I'm sure I I or somebody can help with that :)

Comment: Sure, I will do that. Sorry I am new to this forum so was not aware of the rules.

Comment: No problem!  Just toss a new question up and somebody will see it :)